# How do you get Alexa to read really long texts?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to get Alexa to read a really long text, however Alexa says the skill returned a failed response. When I return only the first 1000 characters of my text it works and reads them out.

How do I get Alexa to read me my very long document?

Comment: I've found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36582445/3176550 that the outputspeech cannot be greater than 8000 characters. How do I get my skill to read more than this?

Comment: Is it possible to feed her the long document piece-wise?

Comment: Just tried that, I can go up to 6000 characters but I'm not sure how to listen for the user to agree to continue.

Comment: Could you use Amazon Polly and play the output as an mp3?