# Alexa stops speaking my output in between

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an alexa custom skill using NodeJs. I created interaction model Intents and handled it in code. My handler returning out as follows.

```
...

return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(outputSpeech)
            .getResponse();
...
```

Where `outputSpeech` is bit long string, about 550 characters, Alexa starts speaking `outputSpeech` but in between some noise occurred and alexa stopped speaking.
I search about maximum characters length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557053/alexa-skill-ssml-max-length), Answer here says that maximum character limit is 8k but my outputSpeech is just about 500-600 characters. What could be the issue? Is it maximum character limit issue or could be something else?

Any idea or direction would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: Can you share the string to see if others can reproduce the issue?